# OnClick function within a image button

Tags: javascript, image, button, onclick

I am trying to create a quiz game that allows the user to simply click on an image as their answer.

I

```js
function checkimage(){
    
}
```

```css
body{
  font: 15px/1.5 Arial, Helvetica,sans-serif;
  padding:0;
  margin:50px;
  background-color:rgba(255, 128, 0, 0.54);
  text-align: center
}


h2{
    padding: 10px;
    background-color: red;
    
}


#container{
    margin : 20px auto;
    background-color: white;
    height: 60%;
    width : 100%;
    border-radius: 5px;
    box-shadow: 0px 5px 15px 0px;
    position: relative;
}

*{
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.column{
    float:left;
    width:100%;
    padding:5px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width"> 
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    
    <title>Quiz</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="game.css">
</head>
<body>
    <h1> Welcome to the Shopping Quiz Game</h1>
    <div id="container">
        <div class = "question">
            <h2>which of the following is a fruit? click on the image </h2>
            
        <div class = "quiz">
            <div class="column">
            <input type="image" id="forest" src="forest.jpg" style="width:50%"> </div> 
            
            <input type="image" id="snow" src="snow.jpg" style="width:50%"
                   onclick="checkimage"> </div>
            


        </div>
              
            
            </div>
        
    <div>
        
       
    <script src="game.js"></script>
        
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

have tried firstly to make the images into buttons which worked because they are clickable.However, i have very basic javascript knowledge and i am not able to do the "on-click" function that once the user clicks the image, the program will check if the image clicked is the right answer and then return a message.

Comment: How to know the right answer? iS there any api ?

Comment: so basically there is a question "which one is the apple" and the user has to click on one of the images , once click the program should check if the image clicked corresponds to the right answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get id value when an image got clicked and then you can compare with your original answer to check whether it's right or not.

```js
function checkimage(element) {
  var rightAns = "Apple";
  if (element.id == rightAns) {
    alert("You selected right ans!")
  } else {
    alert("You selected wrong ans!")
  }
}
```

```html
<h3>Which image is of an apple?</h3>

<input type="image" id="Apple" src="https://www.organicfacts.net/wp-content/uploads/apple.jpg" style="width:25%;height:25%;" onclick="checkimage(this)"></div>

<input type="image" id="Watermelon" src="https://snaped.fns.usda.gov/sites/default/files/styles/crop_ratio_7_5/public/seasonal-produce/2018-05/watermelon.jpg?itok=6EdNOdUo" style="width:25%;height:25%;" onclick="checkimage(this)"></div>
```

> Note that here i am passing reference of an image element to the
>   javascript function on click event like
>   '**onclick="checkimage(this)"**' where '**this**' is a reference.

Answer (score 0):

Hello this is simple if i understood correctly, you need to use hidden values in your html code for example:

```
//OPTION 1:
<img src="IMAGE_PATH_HERE" onClick='answerIs('id_here_or_answer_here')'/>
//OPTION 2:
using hidden values 
<input type='hidden' value='id_here_or_answer' id='answer_{id should be unique}'/>
```

Finally if you are using a loop you could use any option with uniques ID in order to make it work:

```
    function checkimage(id){
    $answer = $('#answer_'+id).val().toString;
    }

//or while//
        for ($i; $i>=10; $i++){
//input or image as you wish
//<inputs OR <img TAGS
        <input type='hidden' value='id_here_or_answer' id='answer_<?= $i; ?>' onClick='checkimage('<?= $i; ?>');return false;'/>
        }
        //end//
```

in fact, you are telling to the JS what ID is the real answer even if you have a lot of options

USAGE in your case:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width"> 
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">

    <title>Quiz</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="game.css">

    <script>
$( document ).ready(function() {
    console.log( "ready!" );

  function checkimage(value){
            alert('answer is:' + value);

            if (value == "apple"){

                //do something
             }else{
               //optionally do something here too  
            }
        }  

});


     </script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1> Welcome to the Shopping Quiz Game</h1>
    <div id="container">
        <div class = "question">
            <h2>which of the following is a fruit? click on the image </h2>

        <div class = "quiz">
            <div class="column">
            <input type="image" id="forest" src="forest.jpg" style="width:50%" onClick="checkimage('apple');return false;"> </div> 

            <input type="image" id="snow" src="snow.jpg" style="width:50%"
                    onClick="checkimage('banana');return false;"> </div>



        </div>


            </div>

    <div>


    <script src="game.js"></script>

    </div>
```

Comment: thank you, where would i input this in my code, could you show me please i am still very new to coding

Comment: You have to insert this in your two ways:

Comment: in your body:  <input type="image" id="snow" src="snow.jpg" style="width:50%"
                   onclick="checkimage('VALUE_HERE');return false;"> </div>                                  in your head <head><script>function checkimage(value){ //your stuff here  alert(value);}</script></head>

Comment: i have added a document.write("well done") if the answer was apple, however it does not display the message when the right option is clicked

Comment: i've edited my answer with your full html code, so you can copy and paste in your own and test it. idk why you are using document.write? and not following my answer? I wondering

Comment: document.write("well done")  I guess this is another question that you need to create and mark my question as Positive or Negative so other users could help and understand you.

Answer (score 0):

```js
function checkimage(id){
$answer = $('#answer_'+id).val().toString;
}



    //or while//
        for ($i; $i>=10; $i++){
//input or image as you wish
<inputs OR <img TAGS
        <input type='hidden' value='snow' id='snow_<?= $i; ?>' onClick='checkimage('<?= $i; ?>');reuturn false;'/>
        }
        //end//
```

```css
body{
  font: 15px/1.5 Arial, Helvetica,sans-serif;
  padding:0;
  margin:50px;
  background-color:rgba(255, 128, 0, 0.54);
  text-align: center
}


h2{
    padding: 10px;
    background-color: red;
    
}


#container{
    margin : 20px auto;
    background-color: white;
    height: 60%;
    width : 100%;
    border-radius: 5px;
    box-shadow: 0px 5px 15px 0px;
    position: relative;
}

*{
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.column{
    float:left;
    width:100%;
    padding:5px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width"> 
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    
    <title>Quiz</title>
    <script>function checkimage(value)</script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="test.css">
</head>
<body>
    <h1> Welcome to the Shopping Quiz Game</h1>
    <div id="container">
        <div class = "question">
            <h2>which of the following is a fruit? click on the image </h2>
            
        <div class = "quiz">
            
             
            <input type="image" id="snow" src="snow.jpg" style="width:50%" onclick="checkimage('snow');return false;"></div> 
            
            <input type="image" id="forest" src="forest.jpg" style="width:50%" onclick="checkimage('forest');return True;"> </div>
            

        </div>
              
            
            
        
    <div>
        
       
    <script src="test.js"></script>
        
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @Crythephoenix - have i put the code in the right way, it doesn't return a message that notify's the user they got the right answer